# Shader: Rounded edge between the two intersecting faces?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, edges

Is there way to do "Rounded Edge Width" in Blender? It's familiar for me from Modo. Anyone know the trick?

**Like Modo's Rounded Edge Width. Couple links for reference:**
From the [modo documentation](http://docs.luxology.com/modo/701/help/pages/shaderendering/ShaderItems/Material.html):

> The 'Rounded Edge Width' option adjusts the rendered result of surface
>   normals at a polygons edge to blend them with adjoining polygon
>   normals, giving the impression of a small rounded edge between the two
>   intersecting faces. To explain it more simply it **shades polygons edges
>   at render time** to look as if a small rounded bevel has been applied,
>   to what normally would be a sharp intersection. Users can define an
>   Edge Width to determine the amount or 'roundness' but keep in mind it
>   is **merely a shading trick and wont round the edges of the actual
>   geometry**, nor change the objects silhouette in the rendered image, so
>   it is best to keep set the length to just a few pixels in width in the
>   final rendered image.
>
> <sub>emphasis mine</sub>

[Video demonstrating the effect](http://youtu.be/TwsomsvF99Y?t=1m4s).

[image: Rounded Edge Width]

Comment: Welcome Sakari! Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: You could try using a Bevel modifier...

Comment: @someonewithpc I think the OP wants to do this with disconnected intersecting faces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an OSL bevel Shader for Cycles that I believe was originally written by the person who built Cycles.  Several people have been making adjustments to it and have been posting the results to the following thread on BlenderArtists.org  http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?329295-Bevel-shader

## OSL Code

Paste the following code into a new Text Datablock in Blender, and use it in the script node of an OSL node tree:

```
void rng_seed(output int rng, int seed)
{
  int chash = seed;
  if (chash == 0) chash = 1;
  rng = chash * 30391861;
}

float rng_uniform(output int rng)
{
  float res = rng / float(2137483647) * 0.5 + 0.5;
  rng *= 30391861;
  return res;
}

void to_unit_disk(float x, float y, output float x_out, output float y_out)
{
  float r, phi;
  float a = 2.0 * x - 1.0;
  float b = 2.0 * y - 1.0;
    
  if(a > -b) 
  { if(a > b) 
    { r = a;
      phi = M_PI_4 *(b/a);
    }
    else 
    { r = b;
      phi = M_PI_4 *(2.0 - a/b);
  } }
  else 
  { if(a < b) 
    { r = -a;
      phi = M_PI_4 *(4.0 + b/a);
    }
    else 
    { r = -b;
      if(b != 0.0) phi = M_PI_4 *(6.0 - a/b);
      else phi = 0.0;
  } }
  x_out = r * cos(phi);
  y_out = r * sin(phi);
}

void make_orthonormals(vector N, output vector a, output vector b)
{
  if(N[0] != N[1] || N[0] != N[2]) a = cross(vector(1, 1, 1), N);
  else a = cross(vector(-1, 1, 1), N);
  
  a = normalize(a);
  b = cross(N, a);
}

vector sample_cos_hemisphere(vector N, float randu, float randv)
{
  vector T, B;
    
  make_orthonormals(N, T, B);
  to_unit_disk(randu, randv, randu, randv);
  float costheta = sqrt(max(1.0 - randu * randu - randv * randv, 0.0));

  return randu * T + randv * B + costheta * N;
}

shader node_occlusion2(
  color Effect = color(0),
  color No_Effect = color(1),
  int Mode = 0, /* 0: Concave (AO) 1:Convex (Wear) 2:Both */
  int InvertEffect = 0,
  float Distance = 0.2,
  int Samples = 1,
  output color Color = 0,
  output float Fac = 0,
  output normal outNormal = N
)
{
  int i, rng;
  float f, randu, randv, ray_t, hits = 0;
  vector ray_P, ray_R;
  normal hit_normal = N;
  float hit_dist;

  f = fmod(cellnoise(P*123456.0), 1.0);
  rng_seed(rng, int(f * 21374647));
  
  for(i = 0; i < Samples; i++) 
  { randu = rng_uniform(rng);
    randv = rng_uniform(rng);
       
    ray_P = P;
    ray_R = sample_cos_hemisphere(-N, randu, randv);
    ray_t = Distance;
    
        
    if (!Mode)
    { if(trace(ray_P, -ray_R, "maxdist", ray_t)) {
            hits += 1.0;
            int HitNormal = getmessage ("trace", "N", hit_normal);
            outNormal = outNormal + (hit_normal);
        }
    }
    else if (Mode == 1)
    { if(trace(ray_P, ray_R, "maxdist", ray_t)) {
           hits += 1.0;
           int HitNormal = getmessage ("trace", "N", hit_normal);
           outNormal = outNormal - (hit_normal);
        }
    }
    else { 
        if(trace(ray_P, -ray_R, "maxdist", ray_t)) {
            hits += 1.0;
            int HitNormal = getmessage ("trace", "N", hit_normal);
            outNormal = outNormal + (hit_normal);
        }
        if(trace(ray_P, ray_R, "maxdist", ray_t)) {
           hits += 1.0;
           int HitNormal = getmessage ("trace", "N", hit_normal);
           outNormal = outNormal - (hit_normal);
        }
    } 
  }
  Fac = 1.0 - (hits/Samples);
  if(InvertEffect) Color = mix(No_Effect, Effect, Fac);
  else Color = mix(Effect, No_Effect, Fac);
  outNormal = normalize(outNormal);
}
```

Here's a render of many spheres that are all separate objects.  It works well in some cases but not always.

[image]

Comment: Just curious, but what makes you think that it was written by Brecht? (I assume that's who you mean). I don't see any evidence one way or another. Not that it really matters though..

Comment: That shader was posted on some other thread before this one.  It was username "BAO" something or other.  He said he got it from Brecht.

Comment: I find this solution to suit pretty well in my cases. There is couple different versions from bevel shader script in that forum thread. Thanks for pointing me to right direction!

Answer (score 5):

We no longer need the OSL script.

Cycles now has a dedicated node to do this.

It's found under Input-> Bevel.  Just plug it into the Normal socket of the Shader.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Blender is this, please? This, (and a few other shaders referred to here), are not  my install of 2.79b,

Comment: The Bevel node was introduced about a year ago IIRC.  Every version since then should have it.  The script that I posted many years ago is not a part of any version.  You have to activate OSL and load it in manually but anything OSL is painfully slow so it's a last resort.  (BTW.  There was a typo in this answer until yesterday)

Comment: OK, thanks, got it.  it's in the official builds [here](https://builder.blender.org/download).

Comment: bevel shader node requires the geometry to be in the same object to work doesn't it?  (Not necessarily linked, but part of the same mesh object).   Possibly i've been using it wrong?

Comment: You're using it right if you get these results although maybe these results are not the best way for the tools to function.  I'd start a thread on BlenderArtists.org to discuss the issue.  The tool author; Brecht-VL, will be change the code if there is a logical reason to do so.  Be sure to post a link here if you choose to start a thread to work on this issue.  Personally, I'd like the option for bevel to affect both separate and joined objects.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Jerryno said](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20999/3078), you need geometry. You could try using a Bevel modifier, or the equivalent Bevel tool in *Edit Mode*. The modifier is however preferable, since it's easily reversible; To do this, go to the *Properties panel*, and in the *Modifiers* tab, click `Add Modifier` and choose `Bevel`.

[image]

Then you can tweak the settings in the modifier to give the effect you want. For instance:

[image]

The number of segments defines the "Smoothness" and the Profile defines in which direction the generated geometry curves. A value less than `0.25` will curve it inwards.

Answer (score 1):

## Creating a Bevel Map for use with Eevee

To expand on [MarcClintDion's answer for Cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/94736/2952), it is also possible to Bake a bevel map from Cycles to use in Eevee.

What isn't obvious is that if you simply bake the normal data to color data, some axes will be out of range in the negative and appear black. This causes the normal data for those regions to be lost. For this reason it is necessary to "compress" the normal data into a positive range of color (`0 to 1`) when baking, and re-expand the colors to the original range of the normal data (`-1 to 1`) when using the baked texture.

### Baking

From the **Bevel** node **Separate RGB**, and for *each* of the three color channels **Map Range** From Min:`-1` From Max:`1` To Min:`0` To Max:`1` then Combine RGB and route it to an **Emission Shader**. As always when baking, make sure your mesh is UV mapped and that the Image Texture inside your Material that you want to bake to is selected. Set the Bake Type to **Emit**. Max Samples `20` is enough for baking Emission.

Baking in Cycles:

[image]

↑ I went with a **Radius** of 0.2 for this example to make the effect obvious, but you might want a lower value for a more subtle effect. This will vary depending on your mesh size and what look you're going for.

Inside the Group node:

[image: Inside the Group node for performing Map Range on each of the RGB channels]

Bake-related settings:

<sup>(Where Image Format and Color Space are concerned, I'm not saying you need these exact settings, but these worked for me.)</sup>

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Using the bevel map in Eevee

From the Image Texture node, separate each color channel again and this time map From Min:`0` From Max:`1` To Min:`-1` To Max:`1`. Recombine the color channels and connect the output to the Normal input socket of the shader you want to use.

[image: Using the bevel map in Eevee]

Final result rendered in Eevee:

[image]

↑ This is lit with several Point lights, which leave hard shadows, but the result could be improved with some nice environment lighting. Lighting in Eevee is another topic though, so I will leave it at this.