# Long and thin connections between 3d metaballs

Tags: meta-objects

Is there a way to create the effect of these long and thin metaball connections in Blender? 
[image: image of long connections between metaballs]

This image is a screen capture from http://paperjs.org/examples/meta-balls/

I Personally haven't had much luck, but I think the way that paper.js does metaballs uses curves instead of a blurred grid.

Anyways, if anyone has an idea on how to do something similar, that would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [animatable soft transition between sphere and cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/animatable-soft-transition-between-sphere-and-cylinder)

Comment: Thanks for the link, although for some reason when I try and connect the instance objects to the transforms output it gives me a "get list element" node.

Comment: after updating animation nodes, no more problems.