# Change Metaball stickyness

Tags: animation, meta-objects

I am using simple **Metaball** objects to create a very simple key-framed animation where two objects collide and "stick" to each other.

[image: animated meta objects moving into each other]

The natural elasticity and stickyness of Metaballs makes it very simple and quick to setup an animation. However, I would love for the two shapes to be more "sticky" together, such as the effect you get when you eat melted cheese for example.

Changing Threshold makes the "Joint" area very big and it doesn't look like the desired effect:

[image: blender with meta object settings]

This is what I want (without changing object size or distance to each other):

[image: desired result]

**How can two Metaball objects "stick" with each other more than the default setting?**

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101687/long-and-thin-connections-between-3d-metaballs

Comment: 10/10 mspaint job my good sir: +1

Comment: @tfbninja updated with another image produced with Bezier Curves, thanks for the feedback

Comment: @MicroMachine anytime my man

Answer (score 7):

Play with the values for Threshold and resolution

[image]

From the [Manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/metas/properties.html#threshold-influence)

**Threshold (Influence)**

> Threshold defines how much a meta’s surface “influences” other metas. It controls the field level at which the surface is computed. The setting is global to a group of Meta objects. As the threshold increases, the influence that each meta has on each other increases.
>
> There are two types of influence: positive or negative. The type can be toggled on the Active Element panel while in Edit Mode, using the Negative button. You could think of positive as attraction and negative as repulsion of meshes. A negative meta will push away or repel the meshes of positive Meta objects.

[image]

Comment: I am unable to reproduce what you show in your captures, when I follow your setup I end up with a big "joint" which is bigger than the two objects [like here](https://imgur.com/a/5ZSP7)

Comment: @MicroMachine please add images that show your settings as well...

Comment: Yes, I have shared the .blend file and added a screenshot