# Should I use Metaballs for hands and hair?

Tags: modeling, mesh, metaballs

I've been trying to teach myself to use Blender so I can make models of my characters, animate them in 3d space, and render them as though I had hand drawn them in 2d. I've been making a lot of progress setting up my line art to look like what I draw using the freestyle option, and making a shader that will do the shading like I normally do, and I'm attempting to mimic my normal art style.

I've been thinking about what else I need to figure out how to do to successfully mimic my art, and I noticed that when I draw hands, I don't draw line art between the fingers where the fingers are touching. This is a tip I learned a long time ago, and it looks really good. I do a similar thing with locks of hair. I was trying to think of how to make my models render this way, and I thought Metaballs might be a good idea, since they fuse when they touch. But the more I look into it, it seems I can't model Metaballs until I bake them into a mesh? At which point it can no longer fuse?

I would like to have a model made with geometry, where the fingers are either made of Metaballs, or have a thin layer of Metaball around them, so that I can animate my character and have the fingers fuse when they touch. And do something similar with the hair, having the hair made of Metaball, so that locks fuse when they touch. Is this possible? If not, does anyone have recommendations for alternative methods. I'm a noob, and am trying to learn all I can.

Comment: Oops, I thought they were called meatballs , should I edit my original question?

Comment: it's okay I already did XD

Comment: Metaballs are too feature limited and not performant enough for most uses. See examples https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244710/19307 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/animatable-soft-transition-between-sphere-and-cylinder/

Comment: I finally got a chance to go test it... it seems metaballs do not play nice with freestyle lineart 